# Created customer but the registered customer is unable to login

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, login, customer-account

```
<?php

namespace ModuleNamespace\Module_Name\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer   = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail("email@domain.com"); 
        $customer->setFirstname("First Name");
        $customer->setLastname("Last name");
        $customer->setPassword("password");

        // Save data
        $customer->save();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: what meassge is showing

Comment: @Amit Bera : the message is "you are not logged in correctly or account is temporarily disabled".

Comment: @Amit Bera  is there any settings in admin side to activate the registered customer.

Comment: Did you tried to set the customer group param along with them?

Comment: @Pavan Kumar: No i didnt set the customer group

Comment: wait wait.. are u trying to create the frontend user or admin user??? bcoz if you try to create frontend user, then it will just show the error as "Invalid login or password.". It will not show as "you are not logged in correctly or account is temporarily disabled". This error msg is related to admin login. are ur sure about this that u have created the frontend user and u r trying at the frontend itself???

Comment: Yes i have created the frontend user because  in admin side it is showing in customer list.

Comment: @Pavan Kumar: Do you have any other code to register customer programatically?

Comment: Man I have just tried with your code and it perfectly went well. I am able to login from the frontend too. It took me to the dashboard. all pretty normal. Check with cache and folder permissions.. Your code is working well..

Comment: If you post code, please explain what this code is supposed to be doing, what actually
happens and where you need help. You should not expect us to run the code in our head and
guess the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my routes.xml with this path **Module\Consumer\etc\frontend\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="moduletestfrontend" frontName="moduletest">
            <module name="Module_Consumer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

This is my Index.php at **Module\Consumer\Controller\Index\Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Module\Consumer\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer   = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail("email@domains.com"); 
        $customer->setFirstname("First Name");
        $customer->setLastname("Last name");
        $customer->setPassword("password");

        // Save data
        $customer->save();
//        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
        echo 'cust created';
        die;
    }
}
```

See the dashboard.

[image: frontend dashboard]